# Google chrome is adding an extra scroll bar when using iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net

IE and Firefox correctly display only the inner scroll bar for a dynamic pdf on an iframe.  However, google chrome is displaying an extra exterior scroll bar:

[image]

Anyone know how to get rid of the extra exterior scroll bar chrome is adding?

Here is the asp.net code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"....

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Detail</title>
    <style>
        #stubbox {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #theframe {
            height: 94%;
            width: 99%;
            position: absolute;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box" id="stubbox">
        <form runat="server" id="select">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td nowrap>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="customers" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" title="Customer:" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="customers_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
        <iframe id="theframe" runat="server" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer in case someone runs into this.  Add the following additional css at the end of the two current styles and problem solved for chrome (and IE and Firefox also work with this):

```
body {
    overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
}
```

So it looks like this now:

```
#stubbox {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#theframe {
    height: 94%;
    width: 99%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
body {
    overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your css try this:

```
#theframe {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Muhammad.  I tried your suggestion but it still shows both scroll bars in chrome.  IE and Firefox are still showing one scroll bar correctly with your suggestion.  The iframe should have a scroll bar since some pdf pages inside the iframe are a couple of pages long.